# $\mathscr{L}_2(\Omega,\mu)$ theorem proofs

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have just quoted part of a theorem I am studying. The questions follow the theorem. Thanks!

***Theorem 8.1*** **The space  $\mathscr{L}_2(\Omega,\mu)$ of functions $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ which are square integrable is separable(in the norm topology) if and only if the measure $\mu$ has a countable basis.**
Proof: Suppose first $\mathscr{L}_2$ is separable, so that there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $\mathscr{L}_2$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, $f\in\mathscr{L}_2$ we can find an integer $k$ with $||f-f_k||<\epsilon$ Let $\mathscr{C}$ be any collection of measurable sets of finite measure. Then for each $A\in\mathscr{C}$, the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_A\in\mathscr{L}_2$, so there is an integer $k_A$ such that: 
$||f_{kA}-\mathbb{1}_A||<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$
Then, if $\mathscr{C}$ is a countable basis we must have :
$||f_{kA}-f_{kB}||>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:A\neq B$
so that $k_A\neq k_B$, and $\mathscr{C}$ must be countable. By lemma this implies that $\mu$ has a countable basis.

(1)Why is $||f_{kA}-\mathbb{1}_A||<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$? I tried to expand it this way $||f_{kA}-\mathbb{1}_A||=\int |f_{kA}-\mathbb{1}_A|^2 d\mu\leqslant\int |f_{kA}|^2 d\mu-\int|2f_{kA}\mathbb{1}_A|d\mu+\int|\mathbb{1}_A^2|d\mu$. I guess as $||f_{kA}-\mathbb{1}_A||<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$ so $\int |f_{kA}|^2 d\mu-\int|2f_{kA}\mathbb{1}_A|d\mu<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$ and I think we can make A as small as we want so that $\mu(A)<\frac{1}{3}\epsilon$, right? I do not know if this is right thinking.

(2)How do I prove $||f_{kA}-f_{kB}||>\frac{1}{3}\epsilon\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:A\neq B$?

Comment: There seems to be some circular reasoning in the proof segment that you posted. Specifically, "Then, if $\mathcal{C}$ is a countable basis we must have  [...] and $\mathcal{C}$ must be countable". Please check if this has been copied correctly.

Comment: The book name is  "Introduction to Measure and Integration" by S.J Taylor. I have checked that out and I have not copied it wrong. Anyway thanks for your feedback!

Comment: This is incorrect. The actual phrase in the book is "Then, if $\mathscr{C}$ satisfies $8.1.1.$ we have [...]".

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding (1)**

As the very first step of the proof you have assumed that $L^2$ is separable. This means by definition that there exists a countable set $\{f_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ that is dense in $L^2$. Being dense in $L^2$ means that for any $\varepsilon >0$ and $f\in L^2$ there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
\Vert f-f_k \Vert_{L^2}\leq \varepsilon.
$$
This is then applied to $1_A$ (in the role of $f$) and $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ (in the role of $\varepsilon$).

You can not 'make A smaller' because you need to show this property for an arbitrarily chosen $A\in \mathscr{C}$.

**Regarding (2)**

You have not copied the theorem correctly. Where you write

"Then, if $\mathscr{C}$ is a countable basis we must have :"

it actually says

"Then, if $\mathscr{C}$ satisfies (8.1.1), we must have".

(8.1.1) is exactly this estimation.